# Crawl pages after login using another url

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a limited knowledge about scrapy. With this code I can do the login in a specific forum. Now I need to set another url after the login:

https://forum.xxx.com/threads/topic-name/page-300

I want to automate a crawl with the range of pages between 300-360. Specifically all elements with this class *messageText*

How can I do that?

```
import scrapy

class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'xxx.com'
    start_urls = ['https://forum.xxx.com/login/login']

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'login': 'xxx', 'register': '0', 'password': 'xxxxx', 'cookie_check': '0'},
            callback=self.after_login
        )

    def after_login(self, response):
        # check login succeed before going on
        if "authentication failed" in response.body:
            self.logger.error("Login failed")
            return

        # continue scraping with authenticated session...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once logged in just yield as many Requests as you need:

```
from scrapy import Request
def after_login(self, response):
    # check login succeed before going on
    if "authentication failed" in response.body:
        self.logger.error("Login failed")
        return
    for i in range(300, 360):
        url = 'https://forum.xxx.com/threads/topic-name/page-{}'.format(i)
        yield Request(url, self.parse_page)


def parse_page(self, response):
    # parse page here
```

Comment: @anvd yes, Request is a class of scrapy. See my edit for the correct import.

Comment: ok, now it works correctly but with a DEBUG: Crawled (403) error, even after setting an user agent. `headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0'}
             yield Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_page, headers=headers)`

Comment: There could be many things that cause 403 response - it means you got rejected by the site. It could be that the url you were trying to crawl is badly formatted or there is something wrong with your request; have you tried opening it in the browser? This is an entire new question and requires quite a bit of debugging, you should open up a new question and note what website you're crawling since every website handles this differently.